# How to disable magit on remote files with tramp?

Tags: magit, tramp

I'm working with Emacs on windows, I usually work locally, but I want to disable magit when I'm working on a remote file.

I'm trying to add a hook that disables magit when it detects that the file is on a remote server. I tried this snippet but it freezes tramp everytime I try to open a remote file:

```el
(use-package magit
    :ensure t
    
    :init
    (add-hook
       'magit-mode-hook
       (lambda () (when (file-remote-p default-directory) (magit-mode -1)))))
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to disable? magit-mode is a major mode for magit buffers, not something that is enabled in specific source files.

Comment: I don't want magit to run git on the remote server everytime I open a file with Tramp. I just want it to work if I'm working with a file on my local machine. I don't know if that's possible really.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an answer or not for you, but Magit mentions a fix for bad performance when using TRAMP in it's docs here: you might try their snippet out.

https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Performance.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Magit will be responsible for that; but `vc` might?

See whether `vc-ignore-dir-regexp` helps.  That has a default value of:

```el
"\\`\\(?:[\\/][\\/][^\\/]+[\\/]\\|/\\(?:net\\|afs\\|\\.\\.\\.\\)/\\)\\'"
```

For ease of editing and reading, let's use `rx` syntax.  The excellent `xr` package on GNU ELPA gives me the following `rx` syntax for the default `vc-ignore-dir-regexp` value:

```el
(seq bos (or (seq (any "/\\") (any "/\\")
                  (one-or-more (not (any "/\\")))
                  (any "/\\"))
             (seq "/" (or "net" "afs" "...") "/"))
     eos)))
```

So let's try the following.  I'm using `tramp-methods` to establish the remote path syntax possibilities.

n.b. The position of the `(eval-when-compile (require 'tramp))` looks very odd, but our usage of the `rx` macro needs `tramp-methods` to be defined at byte-compile time, and this achieves that without unnecessarily loading tramp in other circumstances.  We could alternatively use the `rx-to-string` function instead of the `rx` macro, but this way we retain the slight compile-time performance benefit.

```el
(with-eval-after-load "tramp"
  (eval-when-compile (require 'tramp))
  (setq vc-ignore-dir-regexp
        (rx (seq bos
                 (or (seq (any "/\\") (any "/\\")
                          (one-or-more (not (any "/\\")))
                          (any "/\\"))
                     (seq "/" (or "net" "afs" "...") "/")
                     ;; Ignore all tramp paths.
                     (seq "/"
                          (eval (cons 'or (mapcar #'car tramp-methods)))
                          ":"
                          (zero-or-more anything)))
                 eos))))
```

Comment: I have put the last code in my `init.el` file, but sometimes when I byte-compile this file, it complains about `tramp-methods` not being defined. Apparently this happens when tramp wasn't loaded before byte-compiling, which of course happens when I had not used any tramp files before in this session. However, I don't understand why it needs the value of `tramp-methods` when compiling this. I thought it would only need it after loading `tramp.el`, and then `tramp-methods` would be defined.
I'm now trying to solve this by including `(eval-when-compile (require 'tramp))` in my `init.el`.

Comment: Ah, yes indeed.  `rx` is a macro, so it gets expanded at compile-time.  I think you'll be able to handle this with the somewhat odd nesting of `(with-eval-after-load "tramp" (eval-when-compile (require 'tramp)) ...)`.  I'll edit the answer.